# Use @staticmethod in Django Rest Framework endpoint method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Should I be defining `post`, `get`, etc methods of a Django Rest Framework APIView as static?

```
class HomeView(APIView):
    def get(request):
        etc...
```

or

```
class HomeView(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        etc...
```

What are the pros/cons of each way?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

DRF does not declare `get` and `post` as static methods and neither should you. Here's how the defaults are configured in DRF generics.

It is common in DRF to reference instance methods such as `self.get_object` and `self.get_serializer` from within `get` and `post`.

```
class CreateAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for creating a model instance.
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for listing a queryset.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)


class RetrieveAPIView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for retrieving a model instance.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)


class DestroyAPIView(mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for deleting a model instance.
    """
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)


class UpdateAPIView(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for updating a model instance.
    """
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Understood, thank you

If I were not to use `self` and use `@staticmethod`, would there be a performance difference?

Answer (score 0):

As DRF document, You seems do not need to add @staticmethod decorator

Answer (score 0):

DRF won't function correctly without passing ' self '.

PyCharm does mark these methods as 'maybe static', this is false!

Making them static breaks the calling of the method, since the caller method provides the 'self', and your method does not except it. Essentially your still get the self aliased as request, but your other args are ignored. It is possible that this happens silently, that makes it a fairly nasty bug to find :(.

In terms of performance a 'static' or regular function based view should be slightly faster, since you avoid the creation of the instance, but the difference is probably so small that it is hardly noticeable.